# How to read imessage data in xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, widget, imessage

I want to be able to read imessage data and send the latest messages to a widget to display on the home screen. Only problem is, you can’t read imessage data - end of story.

What might be the best way to get around this? I was thinking of maybe a push notification system where 1 person can go onto the app and send a short message to the other. Is there any better way?

Comment: Are you sure that you can't read it? Look here; /Users/your user name/Library/Messages. I see chat.db, attachments etc there.

Comment: I'm fairly certain it's not allowed, considering any app could just come and steal your messaging data if you downloaded it.

Comment: Also, is that not a mac URL path? this is an iOS app, not macOS

Comment: You might have to wait a while. The European Union is passing a law requiring Apple (and others) to provide API access to comms apps.